# What does "Operator Lock" mean on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, arm, cellular-internet

I am working how I can troubleshoot this error in Windows 10. In the cellular menu of the Windows 10 settings, there is a message saying my cellular connection is "Operator Locked". What does this mean and how can I learn more about fixing this?

My device is a Samsung Galaxy Book2 the (AT&T), and I have a fully unlocked and paid for T-mobile SIM card inside it. T-mobile customer service had no clue how to fix this. I have no contracts, and the device is fully paid off. I don't understand why the device would be shipped to me locked.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to ask AT&T with your IMEI code, they should be able to help you.

Comment: Generally done by the company who sold you the phone, or by the cellular carrier they represent.

Answer (score 3):

The Sony article
[My phone is operator locked. How can I unlock it?](https://support.sonymobile.com/sa-en/xperiaxz1/kb/0231018801b0950b9013ffc786a9b00692f/)
describes this condition:

> You may experience that your device only works with a SIM card from a
>   certain operator. This happens when your device is operator locked.
>
> Note! Sony Mobile authorized service centers do not unlock operator
>   locked phones. Please contact the relevant operator in the
>   country/region of purchase to be informed whether they can provide you
>   with an unlock code. Make sure that you ask the operator for a Network
>   Unlock Code (NUC) as this is the code needed to unlock your device.
>   Sometimes this code is referred to as Network Control Key (NCK).
>
> Devices may be available in different versions depending on the
>   country/region of release. There may be generic versions or operator
>   locked versions. **An operator locked version is customized for a
>   certain operator, and may only work with SIM cards from that operator.**

Your device has therefore most probably been locked by AT&T to a certain
operator, perhaps to AT&T itself. You should contact AT&T Support and
ask for the code and the procedure required to unlock the device.
You will need to have at hand all the details of the device,
including an IMEI code if it has one.